# How to Construct Xpath of an Element

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

The **Xpath** which the Selenium **IDE** generates automatically is not working, I mean the script **fails** as it doesn't find any element with such Xpath?

Is there any way to generate Xpath **manually**?

```
<div id="ext-gen1252" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>
```

This the HTML of that Drop down which is annoying me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/em/button")).click();
```

This is the java/webdriver because that was exported from IDE

Please give me some solution ASAP

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: -1 Post the failing code, example of input, and expected result.

Comment: The question asked is how to construct an Xpath of an element. Why would anyone down vote the question asking for code.

Comment: You can generate the Xpath of an element on your own but not necessarily manually. I use FirePath which is an add on to FireFox browser. With which you just need to click on the web element and it will give you its Xapth. I would advice you to use CSS selector over Xpath though.

Answer (score 2):

Tools like IDE and FirePath can only help you to a certain extent. The xpath example in your question is a perfect example of that. Not only its non-functional, but it is also  hard to guess what element it is targeting. Whats the solution? Learn how to construct Xpath or CSS yourself. There are tons of examples online. Here is for [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

As for your question, the xpath should look like,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='x-trigger-index-0']").click();
```

I would highly recommend [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) over xpath and the reasons of it are also well documented in Selenium community.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='x-trigger-index-0']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create, Fore example: 
Below it is showing Html, then body then div[] and so on..
it will create like "Html/body/div"
You can create your xpath like this.

```
<document>
<html itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope="">
<head>
<body id="gsr" class="hp vasq" vlink="#61c" text="#222" link="#12c" bgcolor="#fff" alink="#dd4b39" onload="try{if(!google.j.b){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}}catch(e){}if(document.images)new Image().src='/images/nav_logo170.png'">
<div id="viewport" class="ctr-p">
```

Answer (score 0):

firepath and xpath helper and many other extensions just generate a based on id elements, it's generally not what you want.

If you are using chrome, you could try the [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-generator/lpfjogcaifigkimnlkepjlkfhpdhebap) which generates xpath smartly with pointing to the element